# How to conditionaly create a new variable containing one or more observations?

Tags: r, nlp, tf-idf

I'm trying to match the post (from Table dataEnArbeit) with its relevent key-word/s and its/their `tf-idf` value/s (from Table arbeit). How do I also copy all relevent words and their `tf-idf` scores in wArbeit and iArbeit respectivly?

```
idataEnArbeit <- mutate(dataEnArbeit, wArbeit = ifelse((str_count(dataEnArbeit$Text, arbeit$feature))>=1, arbeit$feature, NA),
                  iArbeit = ifelse((str_count(dataEnArbeit$Text, arbeit$feature))>=1, arbeit$tfidf, NA))
```

All I get is one word from (arbeit), although there are more.

Comment: Without data it's hard to know for sure, but do the two frames (`arbeit` and `dataEnArbeit`) have exactly the same number of rows? `ifelse` requires that all three vectors (`test`, `yes`, and `no`) be the same length (or length 1, recycled).

Comment: Can you post some data sample and some example of what you want?

Comment: @dataminor No, arbeit has only 50 obs. wihle dataEnArbeit has 30352. arbeit contains the words that I'm looking for in dataEnArbeit.

Comment: @Daniel 
`Gender Gruppe    Datum               Text          TextSize XArbeit wArbeit iArbeit
  <chr>  <chr>     <dttm>              <chr>            <int>   <int> <chr>     <dbl>
1 M      Free Adv~ 2018-06-22 15:52:35 Hey everyone~     3877      14 ich      0.0923
2 F      Free Adv~ 2018-05-03 07:49:27 "ich habe me~      587       7 ich      0.0923
3 F      ExpatBab~ 2017-10-03 19:20:17 "19:20   I h~      783       5 job      0.170 `

`wArbeit`, for example, should contain in the in the first obs. 14 words, but only has 1 ìch`. I want the all 14 words be showen

Comment: Does this data come from a package? If yes, which one? If not, can you provide a reproducible example?